# how to read multiple lines of a file in c

Tags: c

Am trying to read a file which contains the coordinate values for my code. each time i use scanf it reads only the first line...(60,70,200,200).    my question is how do i make my code read all the contents of my file and print it out on the screen.here is my code and file.

```
 FILE.txt:
   S (60,70)(200,200)
   S (30,40)(100,200)
   S (10,20)(80,10)
   S (60,400)(700,200)
   S (160,70)(240,20)

 MY CODE:
 #include <stdio.h>
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 int d;
 int data[4][5];

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
 {

if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
{
    /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
    printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
}
else 
{
    // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
    FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
    if ( file == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Could not open file\n" );
    }
    else 
    {
       int i,j;
      for (j=0; j < 5; j++) 
       {
         for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {  
         fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d);
           data[i][j] = (a, b, c, d);              
           printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a, b, c, d);
          }
      }             

        fclose( file );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a space (or newline character `'\n'`) last in the `fscanf` format string and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, `data[i][j] = (a, b, c, d);` doesn't do what you think (I think). It evaluates `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, but sets the value of `data[i][j]` to the value of `d`. Search for "comma operator".

Comment: hey pals to you all...i got it. just added \n to the scanf

Answer (score 1):

You **must** check the return value of I/O calls such as `fscanf()`. If it's failing, it will return 0 without changing your variables.

Also, this:

```
data[i][j] = (a, b, c, d);
```

Doesn't make a lot of sense in C. Remember that C doesn't have tuples like Python. The above is equivalent to:

```
data[i][j] = d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` loop:

```
const int NumberOfValuesIamGoingToReadAtOnce = 4;

while (fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d) == NumberOfValuesIamGoingToReadAtOnce)
{
    // do some actions with obtained values
}
```

as `fscanf` **returns number of read values** by return value you can judge if EOF achieved or file wrongly written

Comment: You're missing an `=` in the constant declaration.

Comment: Ok, thnx, sometimes for that kind of stuff I use #define, so this mistake arose

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the newline as well:

```
 fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

But why the double loop: you're already reading 4 values at the same time. 
Instead, make it one infinite loop and check whether you've read 4 values; break when you did not read 4 values.

Lastly:

```
   data[i][j] = (a, b, c, d);
```

does not make any sense (as any decent compiler warning will tell you). This, instead, may be where you want your second loop: around the assignement, not the scanf statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to `fscanf()`, you have to careful as you have to make sure the file is in correct format with exact number of spaces like how read in fscanf().

I would recommend using `fgets()` then reading numbers from the string using `sscanf()`.

`data[i][j] = (a, b, c, d);`

This line doesn't do what you think it does. You really don't need another loop as you read all numbers in a line at once.

```
   for (j=0; j < 5; j++) 
       {
         fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d);
           data[j][0] = a;
           data[j][1] = b;
           data[j][2] = c;
           data[j][3] = d;

           printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a, b, c, d);
          }
      }
```

And change `data[4][5]` to `data[5][4]`;

Comment: Wrong, `fscanf()` skips whitespace. And `sprintf()` certainly isn't used to "read" anything.

Comment: @unwind that was meant to be `sscanf()`. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

1. declar data[4][5] to data[5][4]
2. modify the loop
      for (i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d);

   ```
        data[i][0] =a;
        data[i][1] =b;
        data[i][2] =c;
        data[i][3] =d;
        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a, b, c, d);
     }
   ```

Comment: The array should be declared as data[5][4] because the first dimension of the array should be the lines in the text file which number is 5, the second dimension should be the coordinate values of each line which has 4 values for each line. Therefore, the array should be declared as data[5][4]. data[0] is the first line, data[0][0] is the first value in the firs line... and data[0][3] is the last value in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I used `fgets` to read file line per line and I used `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int data[4][5];
char line[128];

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else
        {
           int i=0;
           line[0] = 0;
           while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file))
            {
               sscanf(line, "S (%d,%d)(%d,%d)", &data[i][0], &data[i][1], &data[i][2], &data[i][3]);
               printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n", data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3]);
               i++;
            }
            fclose( file );
        }
      }
}
```